# Is there a built-in way to reference a nuget package as a file in csproj?

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild, nuget

I have a nuget package as a standalone file, I can't upload it to any external package feed. Is there a built-in way in msbuild with modern sdk-based csproj format to reference a nuget package as a single file? I want msbuild to take into account the dependencies specified in the package so that they are taken into account when resolving all dependencies for a project.

Comment: You can use any local directory as a nuget feed. Place your package somewhere and configure nuget to look there before searching nuget.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Visual Studio on Windows:**

Open nuget package manager in Visual Studio and right click the gear icon at the top right. Then with the green "+" button, configure the local folder as a package source.

After doing this, go back to nuget package manager, click the "Package source:" dropdown at the top right and select your newly configured package source.

Now in "Browse" tab, you should be able to see your package.

**CLI:**

[`dotnet nuget add source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source) to add a package source.

Install with [`nuget install -Source sourceName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-install)

Comment: Is there a way to do that from terminal and using dotnet cli? I'm on a mac and I use Rider.

Comment: @AlekseyUsatov I believe it is possible but I don't remember how.

Comment: Add source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source there are some examples of adding local folder of you scroll down the page. Then, you can install from that source with the "-Source" option of "nuget install" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-install

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Can you update your answer with this so people could see this?

Comment: @AlekseyUsatov will do it later